# How do I get out of this Loop on Ubunto boot up?

Tags: ubuntu, services, snap, remmina

[image]

I haven't been able to boot into Ubuntu properly since I installed Da Vinci Resolve. It made me install a bunch of libraries and since then I haven't been able to get in.

Answer (score 0):

Report your [issue here](https://snapcraft.io/remmina).

Disable the `snap.remmina.ssh-agent.service` or remove the snap:

```
sudo systemctl disable snap.remmina.ssh-agent.service
```

or

```
sudo snap remove remmina
```

You can install `remmina` through `apt` or you can install through snap from edge channel.

```
sudo snap install remmina --channel=latest/edge
```

Comment: Which the OP would need to do after booting into single user mode & ensuring the disks are mounted read/write.

Comment: @Bib The systemd service will give up after waiting and the boot process will continue as usually. It doesn't break the boot process.

Comment: I would hope... I've seen startups where it doesn't, especially where the network is involved, no matter how long you wait.